# Change electric and magnetic fields

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

I know from the maxwell's equation that changing electric field induces a magnetic field. Does this statement also hold true for non conservative electric field.

Comment: See Wikipedia: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations

Comment: Maxwell’s equations hold for arbitrary electric and magnetic fields.